# Python: adjusting gmtime output

Tags: python, time

How do I adjust the time returned from `gmtime()`?

```
from time import gmtime, strftime, localtime, strptime
print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
2017-02-09 18:54:31
```

But the time I want should be:

```
2017-02-09 10:54:31
```

Which would require a subtraction of 8 hours. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
a = gmtime()
a.tm_hour = a.tm_hour-8
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-65a0fe0238c0> in <module>()
      1 a = gmtime()
----> 2 a.tm_hour = a.tm_hour-8

TypeError: readonly attribute
```

I also tried:

```
print(gmtime().tm_year, "/", gmtime().tm_mon, gmtime().tm_mday, gmtime().tm_hour-8,":",gmtime().tm_min,":",gmtime().tm_sec)
2017 / 2 8 9 : 56 : 51
```

But the formatting is obviously off and probably a "hacky"/wrong way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import strftime

utc_minus_8hr = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=8)
utc_minus_8hr.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
'2017-02-09 11:31:30'
```